# create a pathName

Tags: android

I want to get the image of a path, but if I use this:

```
String pathname="/path/img.png";
```

If I use the following method:

```
Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeFile (pathname);
```

The variable icon returns me null.

I don't know to create the pathname.

Thanks.
Regards

Comment: is /path an existing folder on your SD card?

Comment: Agree with @Egor on previous comment. In addition, checks that your PNG isn't a strange png that cannot be open by Android (it's possible to show it in the gallery?)

Comment: I have the image in the Desktop. The path is: /Users/Download_image/img.png

Comment: this is definitely a strange thing... You want to create a bitmap using a picture on your commpter desktop? correct me if I'm wrong...
You should have the picture on your phone sd card or you can put it in the drawable folder...

Answer (score 0):

You should have something like this for pathname : "/mnt/sdcard/download/img.png" (if your image is on your memory card).

Comment: Use {Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()} instead of hardcoded paths for added flexibility, readability and portability.

Comment: you are right , he should use Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() , I just wanted to make sure he has the right ideea of how path should look like :D